# Anonymous File Upload in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

Does anyone know how I can have anonymous users (basically all visitors to my site are anonymous as I don't process user registrations) upload a file (.docx for example) on my Drupal 7 website? Do I need a special Drupal module (could not find any) or a PHP hack...

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom module with a block. The block renders a form with a file uploader using the form api. 
When the form is submitted (either by an anonymous user or authenitcated) you can save the file in the public file system. Here's an example of how the form code could look:

```
function mymodule_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['some_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('A File'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('some_file'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

When the form submits, save the file:

```
function mymodule_some_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];

  // Save the uploaded file
  if (isset($values['some_file']) && $values['some_file']) {

    // Do the below to make it permanent otherwise 
    // the file will get deleted when cron runs
    $file = file_load($values['healthcheck_image']);
    file_usage_add((object)$file, 'mymodule', 'mymodule', 1);

    if (!$file->status) {
      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    }

    file_save($file);

    // Save file id to variables
    variable_set('some_file', $file->fid);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not well versed in Drupal development. Thanks on the code but is there an easy to use module out there? I heard that the WebForm module supports file attachments. Anyhow, any help would be appreciated...

Comment: That's OK! Yeah the webform module will do what you need. Download and enable the module and then create a webform node. Once you've done that you can click on the 'webform' tab on the newly created node add a 'file' component. This will allow users to upload a file. Let me know if you have anymore problems!